# syntax error: unexpected end of file in Bash

Tags: bash, shell, syntax

I've just started learning about bash and I can't figure out the problem, the exact error is "syntax error: unexpected end of file".
I have tried to add fi at the end but I still get the same error.

```
#! /bin/bash

echo "Enter the input in the form of 'number' 'operation' 'number' "

read EXPR
if ( $EXPR == "EXIT" ) then exit 0

$IFS=' '
read -ra arr <<< "$EXPR"
result = 0

if [ $arr[1] != '+' && $arr[1] != '-' && $arr[1] != '*' && $arr[1] != '/' ]
then
    echo "syntax error"
fi

if [$arr[1] == '+']
then
    result= $arr[0] + $arr[2]
fi

if [$arr[1] == '-']
then
    result= $arr[0] - $arr[2]
fi

if [$arr[1] == '*']
then
    result= $arr[0] * $arr[2]
fi

if [$arr[1] == '/']
then
    if [$arr[2] == '0']
then
    echo "MATH ERROR"
fi
    result = $arr[0] / $arr[2]
fi

echo "$result"
```

I dont know what to do now. Please anyone can figure out the error?

Comment: Copy and paste your script at https://www.shellcheck.net/ and fix everything it tells you. I also recommend you read something like the [BashGuide](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide), and/or get used to looking up syntax in the [Bash reference manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html).

Comment: You have a *lot* of basic syntax errors here. I recommend spending some more time learning shell syntax before starting to actually write scripts. Start even smaller than this (like, just one `if` instead of a series of them), and if you get a syntax error, make sure you're copying the syntax *exactly*.